# Oracle Dotnet Provider and INSERT ALL statement

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net, psql

I'm using c# and Oracle Dotnet Provider , and trying to insert several rows at once with executeNonQuery() method.

But the query never ends, and the app hangs at this point.

I've already tested the same query on SqlDeveloper tool.

Can anyone tell me if OracleDotnetProvide supports INSERT ALL statement?
And/Or, if there's some way to check what is going wrong with the execution?

Here is the query:

```
INSERT ALL  
INTO ESRI_STG.STD_GIS_CUSTOMER (GIS_ID, GEOM) VALUES (53791115,NULL)
INTO ESRI_STG.STD_GIS_CUSTOMER (GIS_ID, GEOM) VALUES (53791123,NULL)
INTO ESRI_STG.STD_GIS_CUSTOMER (GIS_ID, GEOM) VALUES (53791131,NULL)
SELECT * FROM dual
```

Below is the c# code for query execution. I've tried with and without the explicit transaction:

```
using System;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

        public static int executeQuery(string sql_query)
        {
            using (OracleConnection oracleLink = new OracleConnection(oracleConnectionString))
            {
                using (OracleCommand comm = new OracleCommand(sql_query, oracleLink))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        oracleLink.Open();
                        //OracleTransaction txn = oracleLink.BeginTransaction();
                        int linhasAfetadas = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        //comm.Transaction.Commit();
                        return linhasAfetadas;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e1.Message);
                        return -1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you please show your C# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOUND IT!

I was using Sql Developer, connected with the same credentials, same database, etc.
Once I disconnected from SqlDeveloper, my query ( at visual studio debug ) ran properly.

I don't know the exact explanation, but it seems to be some kind of session restriction, maybe relative to transactions.

Comment: You probably had uncommitted changes in sql developer.